# Why Neto/Shopify use their own templating language?

Tags: shopify, neto

Why Neto/Shopify use their own templating language instead using any popular popular language ?

Comment: How about [asking them directly](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/scripts)?

Comment: Why down vote ?

Comment: This is a poorly worded question, hence the downvotes. This forum is for technical questions about programming, not philosophy. Additionally, when you use phrases like "popular language" you are asking for a fight. What you think is popular might be absolute garbage in someone else's thoughts. 

In other words, ask precise technical questions here, not general personal or philosophical ones. There are other forums for those.

Comment: @David ,it now philosophical question if you could understand this at architecture level.

Answer (score 1):

When you have your own templating language you have full freedom to implement or limit the logic of the language to meet your needs.

You don't need to wait for a third party update in order to implement new stuff or objects.

Why do you think Samsung creates clones of google apps on their phones? To create an experience that they can control in some way and if they like to change or add something to do so and not to wait for google to do so. ( and some other things but that is outside the scope of this question )

Since liquid was a Tobias Lütke creation ( co-founder and CEO at Shopify ) and now is an Open Source project it was written in specific fashion in order to meet specific needs and those needs seems to be fitting for Shopify and other platforms as well.

Being popular doesn't mean being better! This is the wrong way to go.

WordPress is the most popular platform, but is it the best one - NO! There are a lot of hole provided by plugins, poorly written themes and some times core issues. While it's easy to use and extendable it opens a lot of doors for issues if you don't manage it properly.

Beats by Dre is the most popular headphones and quite expensive, does they sound as good as the price tag put on them - NO! You can buy the same quality headphones ( even better ) for less, but you are paying for the brand.

Creating new languages in the coding world is ALWAYS a good thing It might be a chore to learn it if it becomes a standard but that means that it provided something that the other popular languages didn't and this pushes the coding world forward. It's a much better alternative than to be in a standstill like when we had only jQuery and there were no new stuffs to excite the developers.

Now we have so much different things that you can choose the direction you like to go and you won't be able to learn all of them even if you try, which is a great thing to a developer who likes to grow.

**Conclusion:**

Being different is OK as long as that fits your needs and you are not doing it just because it's popular to be different. ( so true IRL now too :D )

Comment: So the Only reason behind is "When you have your own templating language you have full freedom to implement or limit the logic of the language to meet your needs"  ?

Comment: @AshwaniPanwar the only reason is a little too much. There can be too much reasons. The other alternatives doesn't do what you like, their security is under question, they are hard to use, they are hard to implement in your platform and so on. If you want a legit answer only the people who approved to use liquid on those platform can give you concrete answer. We can only speculate why they decided so, but I assume this is what you wanted if you asked such a question in SO.

Comment: I  think we need some more information as every programmer can easily understand the reason what you mentioned but not what the actual reason is. So thanks for replying but still waiting for more reasonable answer.

Answer (score 0):

This reasoning from their Github Wiki lists some of the reasons. [Why Liquid Templating Engine ?](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki)

> Liquid is a template engine which was crafted for very specific
>   requirements
>
> 1. It has to have simple markup and beautiful results. Template engines which don't produce good looking results are no fun to use.
> 2. It needs to be non-evaling and secure. Liquid templates are made so that users can edit them. You don't want your server running code
>      that your users wrote.
> 3. It has to be stateless. The compile and render steps have to be separate, so that the expensive parsing and compiling can be done
>      once; later on, you can just render it by passing in a hash with local
>      variables and objects.
> 4. It needs to be able to style emails as well as HTML.